# IE issue while loading the page

Tags: php, javascript, internet-explorer

I have a website which is running in Chrome and Firefox properly but while I am running the page on IE some problems occur. The first time it loads perfect but after login while I am trying to click another page it takes too long to load the page.

Second problem is after login in IE when I tried to refresh the page the session expired and it sent the user to the login page again.

I am using in meta like this:

```
http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"

http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache"

http-equiv="Expires" content="0"

NAME="robots" CONTENT="noindex,nofollow"
```

I am using JavaScript after the body tag.

In the page header section I wrote PHP code like this:

```
ob_start();
session_start();
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: I think you'll need to provide more code to get help

Comment: what version of ie are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ob_start();
session_start();
```

Change the position of these. Hope it will work

Answer (score 0):

change the places of `session_start()` and `ob_start();`